# Android Studio; BottomNavigationView = null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I don't know why `BottomNavigationView` null. I'm using the Firebase API  and I added some code to add data to JSON file. Now after I did that, one of my Activities just stopped working. It wasn't even the Activity I was working on. My navigation equals null and I checked the XML files. The names are the same and debugging doesn't help either, because it shows me that one line of code that sets the `BottomNavigationView` and gives me a NullPointer.

This is the Navigation that is creating this problem:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener

    = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() 

  {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_to_dos:
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_categories:
                intent = new Intent(ToDos.this, Categories.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_account:
                intent = new Intent(ToDos.this, Account.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And this is the part where I initialize everything concerning the Navigaion in the onCreate() function:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_to_dos);
```

I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: lb335.bbbaden.ch.pendenzenverwaltung, PID: 25288
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lb335.bbbaden.ch.pendenzenverwaltung/lb335.bbbaden.ch.pendenzenverwaltung.ToDos}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3279)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1881)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                  at lb335.bbbaden.ch.pendenzenverwaltung.ToDos.onCreate(ToDos.java:76)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7365)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3279) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1881) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
```

My Activity XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

I'm lost on this one and would really appreciate some help from more experienced Coders.

EDIT:

Thanks to snachmsm I found out, that I had my order of functions was all messed up. I executed `findViewById()` before I actually set the content. I had to switch that out and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a **null object reference**

your `BottomNavigationView` is `null`, thats a fact. this line isn't fetching your `View`:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
```

are you shure your `BottomNavigationView` belongs to inflated layout? `R.id.navigation` is set properly for `BottomNavigationView`? show some XML and more code from `onCreate` method. maybe inproper order? (e.g. `findViewById` called before `setContentView`)

edit: ok, `id` is set properly for `View` inside XML, but you posted only small part of it, show also how do you inflate this XML inside `Activity`

Comment: You are right, actually. I messed up the order and my findViewById was written before the setContentView. Thanks a lot. It works again.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation is returning `false` because you set it to `false`

Kindly check at the end of your navigation and change the return type from `return false;` to `return true;`

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener

= new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() 

 {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_to_dos:
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_categories:
            intent = new Intent(ToDos.this, Categories.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.navigation_account:
            intent = new Intent(ToDos.this, Account.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return false; // Here is the problem. Change it from false to true
}};
```

Also, `BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);`

Comment: The problem is that my BottomNavigationView variable equals null :/ I added the errormessage. It's popping up in the onCreate() function when I try to set my BottomNavigationView variable to findViewById(R.id.navigation)

I tried it out with setting the returnvalue to true but it sadly doesn't change the outcome

Comment: navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem in my case I solved the problem by replacing right home activity in

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seller_home);//here was problem,i was  inflating wrong home activity
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I solved it by adding the setContentView method.

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage);`